# Determining Rational/Irrational Variable from An Equation

Tags: functions, systems-of-equations, arithmetic, roots, irrational-numbers

Let, $R, C$ be functions of $z$, and everything else except $R,C$ are rational number and the below equation holds-

$$\sqrt [3] {R + \sqrt {Q^3 + R^2} } + \sqrt [3] {R - \sqrt {Q^3 + R^2} } - \dfrac b {3 a}=\frac{-B\pm\sqrt{B^2-4AC}}{2A}$$

In other words,

$$\sqrt [3] {R(z) + \sqrt {Q^3 + R(z)^2} } + \sqrt [3] {R(z) - \sqrt {Q^3 + R(z)^2} } - \dfrac b {3 a}=\frac{-B\pm\sqrt{B^2-4AC(z)}}{2A}$$
$$\implies f(z)=\sqrt [3] {R(z) + \sqrt {Q^3 + R(z)^2} } + \sqrt [3] {R(z) - \sqrt {Q^3 + R(z)^2} } - \dfrac b {3 a}-\frac{-B\pm\sqrt{B^2-4AC(z)}}{2A}=0$$

Can we say $z$ is a rational number?

I have tried by simplifying the equation but it gets  complicated, is there any other way to prove that $z$ is a rational/irrational number  number?

**Edit:**

$C(z)=(z+w_1)^2, R(z)= \frac{z^2-z}{2}+w_2$ where $w_1, w_2$ are known rational number.

Comment: This is not clear.  $z$ does not appear in your equation so there are no restrictions on what value it can have.

Comment: @lulu we know all other variables except $z$, can we infer it form the equation and the fact all other variables are rational ?

Comment: Once again, $z$ doesn't appear in your equation, so you can't solve for it.  I think you must be imagining that $R(z)$, etc. are known functions of $z$, but you don't say that anywhere in your question.

Comment: To be precise:  Suppose $R(z)$ and $C(z)$ are identically $0$, and that $b,B,Q$ are $0$ as well ($a,A$ can be $1$, doesn't matter much).  Then your equation holds for all values of $z$ including both rational and irrational values.

Comment: @lulu If I add that  $C(z)=(z+w_1)^2, R(z)= \frac{z^2}{2}-z+w_2$ where $w_1, w_2$ are known, does it help?

Comment: Of course putting $z$ into the equation will help.  But you should also indicate if $w_i\in \mathbb Q$ or not.

Comment: Should add:  on its face it looks like you can say that $z$ is an algebraic number of degree bounded by something one could compute.  My guess is that that is as far as your can go without explicit knowledge of the parameters.

Comment: @lulu everything except $z$ is known, they are rational, i doubt that at some point a square or cubic root will remain, thus we will get an irrational number, thus $z$ will be irrational, but thing is i can't show this, also direct computation is not helping, but i don't see why explicit knowledge of the parameters is necessary, the most important information is that they all (except $z$) rational, so, i am trying to figure out the status of $z$ from the equation .

Comment: Were one to square and cube often enough, you'd get a polynomial with rational coefficients of which $z$ was a root. The coefficients will be functions of your rational parameters.  For the right choices of those parameters it is perfectly possible that you'd get a rational root.  For most choices, I agree that you probably would not. I don't see a short cut.

Comment: Just to say:  if $w_1=0=w_2$ and $b,B,Q=0$, with $a=A=1$ again, then taking $z=0$ works.  Like I say, the parameters matter.

Comment: @lulu 1. "Were one to square and cube often enough," ... didn't get this line, plz clarify, 2. can consider that all parameters are nonzero?

Comment: Try to clear the radicals.   It shouldn't take that many steps...though the expression will be extremely messy.  I am not going to try to produce a non-zero  example, but I doubt it is hard.